# Sample example for Speech to Text in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, speech-to-text

I am new to iOS programming.Can you please tell me how to convert the speech to text in iOS?Is there any API called?Please suggest me how to proceed?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode.

Comment: Then how to proceed?Can you suggest me?

Comment: see my answer. I listed some of the best available frameworks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several libraries for this kind of conversion - I host two of those on GitHub: [libsprec](http://github.com/H2CO3/libsprec) (this uses the Google speech recognition APIs, so it supports multiple languages) and [VocalKit](https://github.com/H2CO3/VocalKit) which uses the high-quality opensource PocketSphinx library  (however, it currently supports English only).

[OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/) uses PocketSphinx as well.

There are some commercial solutions as well: the [Dragon Dication SDK](http://www.nuance.com/for-developers/dragon/index.htm) is a popular, however quite expensive framework.

Comment: This is not really true. Pocketsphinx supports many languages, among them Russian, German, Spanish, Italian, French, Mandarin. You could add your own one with relatively simple effort.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev There's only an English language model for the version I know about, but that might have actually changed over time.

Comment: @TrevorRudolph That's what I say :)

Comment: @H2CO3 ahah funny it be you who responds, glad you could hear my praise, i am very fond of your ipod import libraries and work with googles speech server, they have very much helped me, thnaks for your good work and i hope you keep on putting out great developer libraries

Comment: @TrevorRudolph You're welcome, I'm glad you like my works, something cool is coming in the next few weeks.

Answer (score 4):

[OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/) is one of the best library available.

You could find all the details from their website.