# How do I read in from a mp3 file and display in a label?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, avaudioplayer, audiosession

I want to display a text information on `UILabel` when my mp3 file is playing. It is like song lyrics, so is there any framework or APIs which help me to achieve this? Please help me if any one have an idea on this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: May be this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019806/sample-example-for-speech-to-text-in-ios

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at [LRC notated files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LRC_(file_format))? They have a well defined syntax and are easy to handle in code. You probably won't need a separate framework for handling these files.

Comment: Or perhaps you are just looking for a way to [extract ID3 Tags from an mp3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138118/how-to-extract-id-tags-from-mp3-files-in-cocoa)?